# using redux for state management , action is being triggered but reducer is not dispatching action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-form, react-select

i am using redux for state management, redux-form to select a option from list of option initialised in state ,  every thing is working fine, when i am selecting option my action creator is receiving selected option with value as showen below
[image: in action file]

action file code:

```
export const filteredResultsAction = (ftlr_status) => {
console.log("in action js file , show filtered Results method", ftlr_status);
 return {
   type: FILTERED_RESULTS,
   payload: ftlr_status,
  };
 };
```

but when i console out the action in reducer it is showing

[image]

reducer code:

```
const changeTempReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
 console.log("seeing action in reducer", action.type);
 switch (action.type) {
   case FILTERED_RESULTS:
   console.log("s s s ", action.payload);
   return {};
   default:
    return state;
  }
   };
```

and initial state :

```
 const INITIAL_STATE = {
   options: [
  {
   label: "correct",
   value: "correct",
  },
  { label: "wrong", value: "wrong" },
  { label: "unattempted", value: "unattempted" },
 ],
 };
```

help me out where i am going wrong ?? thanks

Comment: If possible, start using `@reduxjs/toolkit`. Thank me later.

Comment: Is your FILTERED_RESULTS type are the same? If it is not, that could be the reason why it is not matched in switch/case statement.

Comment: yes FILTERED_RESULTS types are same, problem is not with types.. my action creator  is returning the type and payload, but in reducer when i console out the action.type it is showing as @@redux-form/BLUR (as shown above in image).. i think this issue is related redux-form.. any body worked with the redux-form may solve this issue